# Create JSON array in C# with asp.net

Tags: c#, json

How to create a JSON-Array in C# so that we can insert a variable (array of emails) for example "test@gmail;test1@gmail..." into it?

```
[
    {
        "To":[
            {
                "EntryType":2,
                "username":"jack",
                "email":"test@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        "Cc":[
            {
                "EntryType":2,
                "username":"mikle",
                "email":"test1@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "EntryType":2,
                "username":"jone",
                "email":"test2@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        "Bcc":[
            {
                "EntryType":2,
                "username":"luis",
                "email":"test3@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You may need to rephrase this a bit. It's not clear to me what's being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used json2csharp.com to generated C# classes from your JSON. That results in this:

```
public class Recepient
{
    public int EntryType { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}

public class Mail
{
    public List<Recepient> To { get; set; }
    public List<Recepient> Cc { get; set; }
    public List<Recepient> Bcc { get; set; }
}
```

Actually it created four other classes `RootObject`, `To`, `Cc` and `Bcc` but I renamed them to `Mail` and `Recipient`.

To create JSON from these classes, with Newtonsoft.Json, you can do this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public string Demo()
{
    var mails = new List<Mail>();
    var mail = new Mail();
    mail.To = new List<Recepient>{
        new Recepient
        {
            EntryType = 2, 
            username = "jack", 
            email = "test@gmail.com"
        }
    };

    mail.Cc = new List<Recepient>();
    mail.Bcc = new List<Recepient>();

    mails.Add(mail);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mails);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and you will never look back.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm